# 2 dimensional optimization using fminsearch

Tags: macroeconomics, optimization, dynamic-optimization

I have a complicated capital - debt capital structure optimization problem but to start off simple I just added an extra parameter to the stochastic neoclassical growth model to see how the optimization works in Matlab. The code is as follows for the main function:

```
tic
clear all;
close all;
tic
global v0 beta delta alpha kmat k0 s prob a0 s j val g v1 i dmat amat kd l

%set up the fixed paramters
alpha = 0.33; %capital share
beta = 0.95;%discount rate
delta = 0.1; %rate of depreciation of capital
s = 2;


tol = 0.01;%tolerance
maxits = 1000;%maximum iteration
dif = tol + 100;
its = 0;

kstar = (alpha/(1/beta-(1-delta)))^(1/(1-alpha));
cstar = kstar^(alpha)-delta*kstar;
istar = delta * kstar;
ystar = kstar ^ alpha;

kmin = 0.25*kstar;
kmax = 1.75*kstar;
kgrid = 99;
grid = (kmax - kmin)/kgrid;
kmat = kmin:grid:kmax;
kmat = kmat';
dmin = kmin/2;
dmax = kmax/2;
dgrid = 99;
d_grid = (dmax - dmin)/dgrid;
dmat = dmin:d_grid:dmax;
dmat = dmat';
[N,n] = size(kmat);

%polfun = zeros(kgrid+1,3);
v0 = zeros(N,N,3);
v1 = zeros(N,N,3);

amat = [0.9 1 1.1]';
prob = (1/3) * ones (3,3);


while dif>tol && its < maxits
    

for j = 1:3
  for i = 1:N
     for l = 1:N 
      k0 = kmat(i,1);
      a0 = amat(j,1);
      %k1 = fminsearch(@valfun_stoch,[2.3706],[kmin],[kmax]);
      kd = fminsearchbnd(@valfun_stoch,[kmin dmin],[kmin dmin],[kmax dmax]);
      %fun = @(k) valfun_stoch;
    
      %k1 = fminsearch(@valfun_stoch,kset);
      %k1 = fminbnd(@valfun_stoch,kmin,kmax);
      v1(l,i,j) = -valfun_stoch(kd);
      k11(l,i,j) = kd(1);
     end 
  end
end
%g = abs(v1−v0);
dif = norm(v1-v0);
v0 = v1;
its = its+1;
end
toc
```

And the value function is as follows:

```
function val=valfun_stoch(kd)

% This program gets the value function for a stochastic growth model with
% CRRA utility

global v0 beta delta alpha kmat k0 prob a0 s j val g v1 i l dmat amat

g = interp3(kmat,dmat,amat,v0,kd(1),kd(2),a0,'linear'); % smooths out previous value function

c = a0*k0^alpha - kd(1) + (1-delta)*k0 - kd(2); % consumption
if c <= 0
    val = -8888888888888888 - 800*abs(c); % keeps it from going negative
else
    %val = (1/(1 - s))*(c^(1 - s) - 1) + beta*(g*prob(j,:)');
    val = (1/(1 - s))*(c^(1 - s) - 1) + beta*(v0(l,i,:).*prob(j,:)');
end
val = -val; %
```

I am getting so many errors in this mainly:

```
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is
3-by-1-by-3.

Error in fminsearch (line 201)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Error in fminsearchbnd (line 229)
[xu,fval,exitflag,output] = fminsearch(@intrafun,x0u,options,params);

Error in main3 (line 68)
      kd = fminsearchbnd(@valfun_stoch,[kmin dmin],[kmin dmin],[kmax dmax]);
```

Can someone help me with this? I am very new to dynamic optimization.

Thanks